# How can I visualize predicted outcomes of a negative binomial GLM?

Tags: r, plot, glm, predict

I have a dataset of 254 plots. Each plot belongs to 1 out of 6 categorical classess (we'll call them forest_type). Also, each plot has 6 numerical values that correspond to 6 different uses (C, W, M, F, MD, CS and O), and the value is the density of trees with a certain use. What I want to test is if there is a significant difference among forest_types regarding the density of uses. I also want to predict the density of each use that we can expect in a certain forest type. Because of how my data is distributed, I decided to run a negative binomial GLM and use the `predict()` function

```
rep.glm <- glm.nb(density ~ forest_type* use, data = repsubset)
rep.preds <- predict(rep.glm, type = "response")
repsubset <- cbind(repsubset, data.frame(rep.preds))

> repsubset
  plot_id forest_type use    density    rep.preds
1   A_01     MonoUso   C  855.55556 8.041026e+02
2   A_01     MonoUso  FW    0.00000 6.425641e+02
3   A_01     MonoUso   M  855.55556 8.661538e+02
4   A_01     MonoUso   F    0.00000 1.487179e+01
5   A_01     MonoUso  MD    0.00000 8.923077e+01
6   A_01     MonoUso  CS    0.00000 1.367521e+00
7   A_01     MonoUso   O    0.00000 3.538462e+01
8   A_02     MonoUso   C  877.77778 8.041026e+02
9   A_02     MonoUso  FW  877.77778 6.425641e+02
10  A_02     MonoUso   M  877.77778 8.661538e+02
11  A_02     MonoUso   F    0.00000 1.487179e+01
12  A_02     MonoUso  MD    0.00000 8.923077e+01
13  A_02     MonoUso  CS    0.00000 1.367521e+00
14  A_02     MonoUso   O    0.00000 3.538462e+01
```

I want to plot these predicted outcomes `(rep.preds)`, but I do not know how. I tried the following:

```
ggplot(repsubset, aes(x = use, y = rep.preds)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = factor(use))) +
  facet_wrap(~forest_type)
```

but since each interaction forest_type*use has an unique value, I dont get any boxplot, i just get some lines corresponding to the medians:
[image: predictions plot]

What can I do for best visualizing these predicted densities and how can I visually se the significance between groups?

Comment: Hi @Miguel Ruiz, Could you please provide us your data using `dput(repsubset)`? Then it will be easier for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi Quinten, thanks for your answer. How can I upload the output of ```dput(repsubset)``` ? It is a very long text document.